# Why do I have ambiguous call between UrlEncode(byte[]) and UrlEncode(string)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm currently writing a web application and I stumble upon a weird issue.
I have the code below for my view:

`@using (Html.BeginForm("action", "DO", new { ReturnUrl = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Convert.ToString(ViewBag.ReturnUrl)) }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "row-border", role = "form", enctype = "multipart/form-data", id = "form" }))`

I force cast my dynamic variable `ViewBag.ReturnUrl` to string to ensure that I'm using the Overloaded method of HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string), but it still gives me the error

`The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string)' and 'System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(byte[])'`

Comment: you shouldn't need to encode this in the first place. the html helper will do that for you

Comment: this is my first project using this, and i just saw the tutorial doing this. do you mean i can just put ```ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl``` directly?

Comment: I tried removing the encoding, and still gives me same error @DanielA.White

Comment: Is this an actual build error, or just intellisense acting up?

Comment: @marsze, Runtime error, from a published application. ```Exception Details: Microsoft.CSharp.RuntimeBinder.RuntimeBinderException: The call is ambiguous between the following methods or properties: 'System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(string)' and 'System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlEncode(byte[])'```